# Regex.Matches return zero result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't point on the problem.

I have this line in my C# code:

```
string match = "Test - Wow";
MatchCollection contact = Regex.Matches(match, "-");

//Expected output in contact : contact[0]=="Test " & contact[1]==" Wow" ;
```

But for some reason contact return empty, Meaning no match for `"-"`.
I even tried `@"-"`, `"(-)"`, `"(-)*"`, `"[-]"`, `"([-]*)"` but nothing works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why regex? use split instead.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this, but I already start with this. I will use split if it won't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Ofear: _"Could it be I need to put `Regex reg = new Regex()`?_" Why ask if you could just as well try this on your own?

Comment: Regex.Matches with `-` would only return `-` because that is the character your regular expression matches. In your input string only once.

Comment: Oh! I'm such a stupid. Tnx! @Matten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It works correctly!

```
string match = "Test - Wow";
MatchCollection contact = Regex.Matches(match, "-");
int count = contact.Count; // returns 1
Match onematch = contact[0];
string str = onematch.ToString(); // returns -
```

Test here http://ideone.com/LWTQWn

If you want a regex that will return ALL the string if a `-` is present, something like this `.*-.*` will do (any number of any character, one -, any number of any character)

Answer (score 1):

- is a reserverd character for a Regex. You 'll need "-" (slash-minus). What will be found is '-'. When you want to find Test and Wow you have to use the Regex.Split() function.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regex for this task. Better to use split function.

```
 "Test - Wow".Split('-').Select(x => x.Trim())
```